# Creating a thumbnail from an image

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from an image, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

/* read the source image */
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

/* copy source image at a resized size */
imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);

} //end of function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width)

make_thumb("uploads/643Full-HD-Space-Wallpapers-Widescreen.jpg", "test", 100);

?>
```

Comment: make_thumb function image path correct should it be ../uploads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function works for me, however, I had to give the destination a jpeg extension for it to be a valid jpeg image:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------vvv
make_thumb("uploads/643Full-HD-Space-Wallpapers-Widescreen.jpg", "test.jpg", 100);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, this would be the full function:

```
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width)
    {
        // Make directory if not made
        if(!is_dir($dest))
            mkdir($dest,0755,true);
        // Get path info
        $pInfo  =   pathinfo($src);
        // Save the new path using the current file name
        $dest   =   $dest."/".$pInfo['basename'];
        // Do the rest of your stuff and things...
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $width = imagesx($source_image);
        $height = imagesy($source_image);
        $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
    }

// Create file here
make_thumb("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_250,q_90/happy_dog.jpg", "test", 100);
```

Comment: The destination is a folder named test.

Comment: Then you need to do `test/whatever.jpg` and if the folder is not made, you have to use `mkdir()`.

Comment: You would need to extract the name of the file using `pathinfo($src)` or what-have-you if you wanted the name to be auto-saved as the original.